# re.findall() was working but now isn't finding the pattern I need

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, parsing

To preface I am working in Python 3.8.3 on windows 10 and using `slate3k` to parse through my pdf

I am working on a python program that will parse through a PDF and spit out a certain pattern and make a csv file for me.

However, when I try find the pattern with the parsed text, I am getting nothing.

I've taken an example of some parsed text and assigned it to `parsed`

```
import re

parsed = '7\n\n8\n\n6\n\n1\n\n2\n\nF\n\nNOTES\n\n3\n\n4\n\n5\n\n7\n\n6\n\n5\n\n4\n\n3\n\nA\n\n8\n\nE\n\nD\n\nC\n\nB\n\nR\n\nV\nE\n\n.\n\nR\nD\n\nA\n\nW\n\nI\n\nN\n\nG\n\nN\n\nO\n\n.\n\nP\n\nL\n\nO\n\nT\n\nS\n\nC\n\nA\n\nL\n\nE\n\n:\n\n2\n\n1\n\nA\n\nB\n\nC\n\nD\n\nE\n\nREFERENCE DRAWINGS\n\nDATE\n\nREV.\n\nBY\n\nCHK. ENG. APP.\n\nD\n\nM\n\nY\n\nDESCRIPTION\n\n\n\nTITLE\n\nEQUIP. NO.\n\nSAP NO.\n\nDRAWN BY\n\nAPPROVED\n\nDRAWING NO.\n\nSCALE\n\nCHECKED BY\n\nPLANT AREA\n\nFILE NAME\n\nMICRO. REV.\n\nREV.\n\nG\n\nD\n\n0\n0\n\n-\n\nA\n\n-\n\n0\n4\n0\n1\n\n-\n\n1\n\nR\n\ne\n\nv\n\n5\n\nA\n\n1\n\nS\n\ni\n\nz\n\ne\n\n\n1B\n\nD\nD\n\n6\n8\n\n-\n\nL\n\n-\n\n0\n0\n9\n\n-\n\n1\n\n1\n\nB\n\n\n\nN.T.S.\n\n1\n\n:\n\n2\n\n\n\n-\n\n1A\n\n18\n\n02\n\n22\n\n\n\n\nSCALE - NTS\n\n1.\n2.\n81PEW1002, 81PEW1003 AND 81PEW1004 ARE.\n\n3.\n\n4.\n\n5.\n\nSCALE\n\n6.\n\n7.\n\n8.\n\n9.\n10.\n11.\n12.\n13.\n\n14.\n\n15.\n\n8\n\n1\n\nP\n( E\n\nE\nX I S\n\nW\n\n1\n0\nT I N\n\n0\n\n2 - 4\n\n2 "- C\n\nA\n\nJ\n\nG )\n\n8 1\n\nP\n( E\n\nE\nXI S\n\nW\n\n1 0 0 4-4 2"- C\n\nA J\n\nTI N\n\nG )\n\n3\n\nAREA LIMIT N 252510\nSIPHON C TIE IN DETAIL\n\nPL81-L-147-1\\/1210-1\n\nSCALE - NTS\n\n81PEW1002-42"-CAJ\n(EXISTING)\n\n2\n\nAREA LIMIT N 252497\nSIPHON B TIE IN DETAIL\n\nPL81-L-147-1\n\nSCALE - NTS\n\n81PEW1003-42"-CAJ\n(EXISTNG)\n\n8\n\n1\n\nP\n\nE\nX I S\n\nW\n\n1\n0\nT I N\n\n0\n\n3 - 4\n\n2 "- C\n\nA\n\nJ\n\n( E\n\nG )\n\n81PEW1004-42"-CAJ\n(EXISTING)\n\nDRAIN\n\nA\n\nDRAIN DETAIL\n\n-\n\nSCALE - NTS\n\nA\n\n-\n\nA\n\n-\n\nA\n\n-\n\n81PEW1002-42"-CAJ (SIPHON C)\n81PEW1003-42"-CAJ (SIPHON B)\n81PEW1004-42"-CAJ (SIPHON A)\n\n45°\n\nF\n\nL\n\nO\n\nW\n\nF\n\nL\n\nO\n\nW\n\nF\n\nL\n\nO\n\nW\n\nSIP\n\nH\n\nO\n\nN A\n\nSIP\n\nH\n\nO\n\nN B\n\nS I P\n\nH\n\nO\n\nN A\n\nTP\n05\n\nTP\n06\n\nF\n\nL\n\nO\n\nW\n\nF\n\nL\n\nO\n\nW\n\nF\n\nL\n\nO\n\nW\n\nTP\n03\n\nTP\n04\n\nTP\n02\n\nTP\n01\n\nS I P\n\nH\n\nO\n\nN B\n\nS I P\n\nH\n\nO\n\nN C\n\n5\n\n\n\n5\n\n\n\n5\n\n\n\nS\n\nI\n\nP\n\nH\n\nO\n\nN\n\nC\n\n4\n\n\n\n4\n\n\n\nE\n\nXI S\nA\n\nTI N\n\nG 4 8"\n\nC\n\nS I N\n\nG ( T\n\nY\n\nP .)\n\n4\n\n\nTEE\nDETAIL\n\nDRAIN\nSPOOL\n\n60°\n\nTYP.\n\nTEE\nDETAIL\n\nDRAIN\nSPOOL\n\n60°\n\nTYP.\n\nNOTE 14\n\nA\n\nR\n\nA\nE\n\nL\n\nI\n\nM\n\nI\n\nT\n\nE\n\n5\n8\n0\n8\n4\n1\n\nA\n\nR\n\nA\nE\n\nL\n\nI\n\nM\n\nI\n\nT\n\nE\n\n3\n9\n0\n8\n4\n1\n\nAREA LIMIT N 252504\n\nA\n\nR\n\nA\nE\n\nL\n\nI\n\nM\n\nI\n\nT\n\nE\n\n0\n9\n0\n8\n4\n1\n\nA\n\nR\n\nA\nE\n\nL\n\nI\n\nM\n\nI\n\nT\n\nE\n\n9\n9\n0\n8\n4\n1\n\nAREA LIMIT N 252517\n\nA\n\nR\n\nA\nE\n\nL\n\nI\n\nM\n\nI\n\nT\n\nE\n\n0\n2\n1\n8\n4\n1\n\nA\n\nR\n\nA\nE\n\nL\n\nI\n\nM\n\nI\n\nT\n\nE\n\n8\n2\n1\n8\n4\n1\n\nAREA LIMIT N 252459\n\nAREA LIMIT N 252467\n\nDRAIN\nSPOOL\n\nTEE\nDETAIL\n\n60°\n\nTYP.\n\nNOTE 15\n\nNOTE 15\n\nNOTE 15\n\nSEE MT81-L-PEW1003-1\n\nSEE MT81-L-PEW1002-1\n\nSEE MT81-L-PEW1004-1\n\nSEE MT86-L-PEW1218-1\n\nSEE MT86-L-PEW1217-1\n\nSEE MT86-L-PEW1216-1\n\nCUT BACK EXISTING INSULATION\nFOR INSTALLATION OF FLANGES\nAND TEE\n\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n\x0c'
rawtags = re.findall(r'[0-9]+[A-Z]+-[0-9]+|[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]{1-5}|[0-9]{3}[A-Z]+[0-9]+', parsed, re.I)
print(rawtags)
```

I had this pattern working in a previous iteration but I am having issues here. Any insight as to why it isn't working for me now would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I was expecting a list of `['81PEW1002', '81PEW1003', '81PEW1004'... etc]`

There are two distinct patterns I am trying to catch:

1. `##XXX-#####`
2. `##XXX#####`

Comment: Hey JT, just curious if what your output is suppose to look like. I am guessing something like this?
['81PEW1002', '81PEW1003', '81PEW1004', '81PEW1002', '81PEW1003', '81PEW1004', '81PEW1002', '81PEW1003', '81PEW1004']

Comment: yeah, that is what I was expecting.

Comment: There are a few other patterns but in this particular data set that is what i'm expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an extra minus - symbol

```
rawtags = re.findall(r'[0-9]+[A-Z-]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[A-Z-]+[0-9]{1-5}|[0-9]{3}[A-Z-]+[0-9]+', parsed, re.I)
```

I think the above is something you are looking for.
V/R
Steven M

Comment: So there are cases where the tag pattern is `###XXX-#####`. However, my second expression should have caught them, no? `[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]{1-5}`

Comment: Oh, I see... The minus sign needs to be inside the square brackets. You should put them either after the letters, inside the square brackets or before the numbers, inside the square brackets. I have updated the snipette above. I hope it helps.